# Mathjax not rendering latex formula

Tags: ruby-on-rails, latex, rendering, formula, mathjax

Within my rails application I use mathjax (TEX-AMS_HTML) to render latex formulas.

When entering formulas in a comment I use the codecogs Equation Editor with TinyMCE.

My current mathjax config ontop of (TEX-AMS_HTML) is:

```
        "HTML-CSS": {linebreaks: { automatic: true, width: "container" }},
        displayAlign: "left",
        extensions: ["tex2jax.js","MathMenu.js","MathZoom.js"],
        jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
        TeX: { extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js","noErrors.js","noUndefined.js"] },
        tex2jax: { ignoreClass: "w1", processClass: "active|comments-content" }
```

My problem is that some formulas are not rendering out, consider the following:

```
\[ foo\textup{bar} \]
```

This renders foo **\textup** bar.  I have also noticed some symbols rendering textually such as:

```
\[ \AE \SS \]
```

This would render **\AE \SS** instead of the appropriate symbols.

I have tried switching to SVG, adjusting inline/display settings and cannot solve this.

Anyone have some idea as to why this is happening?

**EDIT:** Here is a contained example

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Mathjax</title>
        <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
            MathJax.Hub.Config({
            "HTML-CSS": {linebreaks: { automatic: true, width: "container" }},
            displayAlign: "left",
            extensions: ["tex2jax.js","MathMenu.js","MathZoom.js"],
            jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
            TeX: { extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js","noErrors.js","noUndefined.js"] },
            tex2jax: { ignoreClass: "w1", processClass: "active|comments-content" }
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="main">
                <div class="w1">
                    <div class="comments-content">
                        <p>\[foo\textup{bar}\AE\SS\]</p>
                        <p>\[K_{E}=\frac{1}{2}m(\frac{80}{3.6})^{2}\]</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Which renders as: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGoYW.png

Notice that whilst mathjax is working and correctly renders the 2nd line, the first line of latex is not escaped.

**EDIT2 (22/06/2017):**
"Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your answer for future readers)" - Thanks to user [Peter Krautzberger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1339651/peter-krautzberger)
Basically this means the cdn used in my code example will need to be replaced with a localised version of mathjax.

Comment: We need a [self-contained test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to have any hope of helping.

Comment: Ok zach i'll do my best - check back when you get the chance

Comment: Try adding this parameter to tex2jax: `inlineMath: [["\[","\]"]`

Comment: Inline math is \\( not \\[ So I'm afraid that won't work

Comment: You can use various parameters in `inlineMath`. Give it a try :) Use it as `inlineMath: [["\\[","\\]"]`.

Comment: Yes I am aware however this is not inline math; the issue isnt that mathjax isnt detecting and rendering my formulas, it is that particular parts of formulas are rendering bright red text and not the desired formatting.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your answer for future readers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macros `\textup`, `\AE`, and `\SS` are not part of the default MathJax TeX macros and are not defined in your inline configuration, which is why the rendering in the image has them marked in red.

You'll see a more specific error if you remove the `noundefined` and `noerrors` extensions from your configuration -- which are also in [the combined configuration `TeX-AMS_HTML`](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/config-files.html#the-tex-ams-html-configuration-file), so you'll need to drop that as well; as you can see from the link, your inline configuration entails all of `TeX-AMS_HTML`. (In production, it's preferable to use a combined configuration file since they load as a single large file.)

For a list of all default MathJax macros, see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands.

For how to define macros in MathJax, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139699/equivalent-of-mathup-for-upright-text-in-math-mode. From there an example:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: {
    Macros: {
      RR: "{\\bf R}",
      bold: ["{\\bf #1}",1]
    }
  }
});
```

i.e., add a `Macros` block to the `TeX` block in your configuration.

(A particular case is`\textup`, which is a LaTeX *text mode* macro and MathJax focuses on *math mode*. Depending on the use case, the math equivalent might be `\text{}`, `\mathrm{}`, or something else, see [this TeX.SE questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139699/equivalent-of-mathup-for-upright-text-in-math-mode). Of course you can define `\textup` to be whatever you like but you might run into trouble backporting content to real TeX).

Comment: Note that you can disable the noUndefined extension with `TeX: {noUndefined: {disabled: true}}` in your configuration, so you can still use `TeX-AMS_HTML`.